# Displaying additional User Contact Information

Tags: custom-field, facebook, user-meta, twitter

I have been advised how to add additional contact info fields to the User admin area here ([Click here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32496/best-way-to-allow-manageable-social-media-urls/32502#32502)).

However, I am not entirely sure how I can display the the field contents in a link within my template files.

Here is the code in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'more_contactmethods' );
function more_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter URL';
    $contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL';
    $contactmethods['linkedin'] = 'LinkedIn URL';
    return $contactmethods;
}
```

And here's the code in one of my template files, but it doesn't seem to work, so I wonder whether I can actually do it this way?

```
<?php 
    $twitter = get_usermeta( $user_id, 'facebook' ); 
    $facebook = get_usermeta( $user_id, 'twitter' );
    $linkedin = get_usermeta( $user_id, 'linkedin' );
?>

    <a href="<?php echo $twitter ?>" id="twitterBtn" title="Visit our Twitter page">Visit our Twitter page</a>
```

Comment: get_usermeta has been depreciated and replaced with get_user_meta. Also can you verify $user_id has a value?

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused by this now...sure there is a value for $user_id? Also, why wouldn't `<?php echo ($contactmethods['twitter']) ?>` work?

Comment: The `$contactmethods` array is only available when you use the `user_contactmethods` filter. To access the user metadata, you need to use the `get_user_meta` function. Can you actually verify the data is getting into the database? You may need to hook `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` to actually save the data.

Comment: What does a `<?php var_dump( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_contactmethods' ) ); ?>` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you out if you haven't found an answer yet.

```
/* BEGIN Custom User Contact Info */
 function extra_contact_info($contactmethods) {
     unset($contactmethods['aim']);
     unset($contactmethods['yim']);
     unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
     $contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook';
     $contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
     $contactmethods['linkedin'] = 'LinkedIn';
     return $contactmethods;
 }
 add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'extra_contact_info');
 /* END Custom User Contact Info */
```

Displaying it:

```
<a href="<?php the_author_meta('facebook', $current_author->ID); ?>"></a>
```

http://thomasgriffinmedia.com/blog/2010/09/how-to-add-custom-user-contact-info-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add/Remove Contact Methods
function add_remove_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
    $contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook';
    $contactmethods['Youtube'] = 'YouTube';
    $contactmethods['linkedin'] = 'LinkedIn';
        $contactmethods['skype'] = 'Skype';
    // Remove Contact Methods
    unset($contactmethods['aim']);
    unset($contactmethods['yim']);
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','add_remove_contactmethods',10,1);
```

This works fine in Thesis. Here's the full tutorial

http://wpsites.net/how-to-wordpress/how-to-addremove-custom-user-profile-contact-info-links-to-your-author-box/

Comment: Thanks @BradDalton, I think I'm having trouble with the code to actually echo the value though. Can you help with this?